# Необходимо вставить текст в переменную в smarty

Tags: smarty

В данном коде выводится город:

```
{%$allregions[$message.region].name%}
```

Как вставить в эту переменную текст, что бы было: "**в** город"

Answer (score 2):

зачем что-то добавлять в переменную, если шаблоны созданы как раз для обратной задачи?

```
<div>
  <b>в</b> {%$allregions[$message.region].name%}
</div>
```

---

апдейт по комментариям

1. Если используется некий общий шаблон для вывода, а исправить надо только в одном  месте, то просто не используйте этот шаблон для данного конкретного случая.
2. Если использовать хочется, то можете передать в шалон доп. параметр и с помощью `if`-ов регулировать вывод доп. символов.
3. передайте выводимую строку как параметр шаблона,

то есть допустим, ваш шаблон, назовем его, `title_inc.tpl` выглядит так

```
{%foreach from=$title_reverse item='tit' name='i'%} 
    {%$tit.name|strip_tags%} 
    {%if $smarty.foreach.i.last eq false %}        
        {%$allregions[$message.region].name%} / 
    {%/if%}
{%/foreach%}
```

то подключайте его следующим образом

```
{$r = "в ".$allregions[$message.region].name} 
{include "title_inc.tpl" rname=$r}
```

а сам шаблон измените так

```
{%foreach from=$title_reverse item='tit' name='i'%} 
    {%$tit.name|strip_tags%} 
    {%if $smarty.foreach.i.last eq false %}        
        {%$rname|default:%$allregions[$message.region].name%} / 
    {%/if%}
{%/foreach%}
```

вариаций может быть много, например

```
{include "title_inc.tpl" prefix="в "}
...
    {%if $smarty.foreach.i.last eq false %}        
        {%prefix%}{%$allregions[$message.region].name%} / 
    {%/if%}
```

Этот вариант, наверное, более удобен и гибок в будущем.

Вообще не понятно, конечно, зачем вам тэги `{% %}` вместо обычных `{ }`, имхо усложняет читаемость кода. Вдобавок смарти 3, куда лаконичнее выглядит:

```
{foreach $title_reverse as $tit} 
    {$tit.name|strip_tags} 
    {if !$tit@last}        
        {$prefix}{$allregions[$message.region].name} / 
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Дело в том что используется такой код для тайтла, где выводится название + город, но если в этот код вставляю просто "в" то оно выводится везде. Поэтому надо именно в эту переменную, что написал выше.

Comment: {%foreach from=$title_reverse item='tit' name='i'%}
   {%$tit.name|strip_tags%}
   {%if $smarty.foreach.i.last eq false %} {%$allregions[$message.region].name%} / {%/if%}
   {%/foreach%}

Comment: @sander обновил ответ

Comment: Не совсем понял куда этот код вставить "{$r = "в ".$allregions[$message.region].name} 
{include "title_inc.tpl" rname=$r}" ?

Comment: Подскажите, а если назначить к примеру {%$locale.1019%} и в нем написать "в". Можно ли вставить в эту переменную? {%$allregions[$message.region].name%}

Comment: @sander вы этот код выводите несколько раз, говорите. покажите как вы это делаете. внесите дополнения в свой вопрос

Comment: Можно ли через назначенный locale вывести этот предлог? Пробовал спереди функции ставить, но потом этот предлог дублируется везде. Прошу прощения за глупые вопросы, впервые со smaty.